# Error in kmeans(mat, centers) : more cluster centers than distinct data points

Tags: r, k-means, complexheatmap

I want to plot a heatmap for my input`mrna_deconv` using the ComplexHeatmap package.
The `row_km` applies k-means clustering on rows. If the value is larger than 1, the heatmap will be split by rows according to the k-means clustering.

Code:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)

row_km = ncol(t(mrna_deconv))-1
Heatmap(t(as.matrix(t(mrna_deconv))), name = "mRNA", row_km = row_km, col=mrna.col, show_row_names=TRUE, show_column_names=FALSE, show_row_dend=FALSE)
```

Traceback:

```
Error in kmeans(mat, centers) : 
  more cluster centers than distinct data points.
```

Input:

```
> dim(mrna_deconv)
[1]  28 166

> dput(mrna_deconv[1:10,1:10])
structure(list(TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 = c(0, 0.0409227767244807, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.351617771147991, 0.0874153582385608, 0, 0.181772456644037
), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 = c(0, 0.02991533249762, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.340011889094215, 
0.108785286587523, 0, 0.199858678474956), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01 = c(0, 
0.0296918459782142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.296641234912303, 0.100551635314064, 
0, 0.164095782525901), TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01 = c(0, 0.0197225903735211, 
0, 0, 0, 0.005625184851424, 0.265789421116835, 0.11036843733851, 
0, 0.190301998904762), TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01 = c(0, 0.0506430272529989, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.321750942332837, 0.07680559708907, 0, 0.146217739550562
), TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01 = c(0, 0.0289269562400886, 0, 0, 0, 0.0467023827588638, 
0.0904484780838239, 0.107838580255164, 0.0529934482238177, 0.144075063451225
), TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01 = c(0, 0.0203195082892011, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33893336182288, 
0.0501685493926867, 0, 0.272718188315665), TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01 = c(0, 
0.00872511598871086, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.328168453426525, 0.0856889817939333, 
0, 0.149557465101895), TCGA.4A.A93W.01 = c(0, 0.0198721808021985, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0921068773935397, 0.103863526495157, 0.0978161334714752, 
0.183588973080623), TCGA.4A.A93X.01 = c(0, 0.0458104097651123, 
0, 0, 0, 0.055944046487111, 0.106248085127836, 0.087253111672165, 
0.0346258754734651, 0.160117115506731)), row.names = c("B.cell", 
"CD16..Monocyte", "CD1C..DC", "CLEC9A..DC", "CXCL10.Hi.TAM", 
"Cycling.CD8..T.cell", "Cycling.TAM", "Effector.T.Helper", "Endothelial", 
"FGFBP2..NK"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Already tried `heatmap(as.matrix(mrna_deconv))`?